JMETER total average not correct?
So i downloaded csv file from jmeter it's look like this
my table
i tried to sum all the average manually but when i am comparing it to total from jmeter it's doesn't match.
is my calculation wrong? or did i miss something, please help.
so for example the value if add all average from my table is  176699 but in total is 25734
i expect the total from jmeter and my calculation is same

Your calculation is wrong. You don't get the average for a population by adding together all the averages for subsets of that population. Consider that the maximum value for each subset ranges from 35k to 67k and ask yourself whether it makes sense that the average would be more than the maximum.

What he says: you are creating a sum of averages and expect it to be the same as the overall average. That doesn't compute.

JMeter .jtl results file is basically a CSV file which looks like:
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1720617130594,226,HTTP Request,404,Not Found,Thread Group 1-1,text,false,,1578,136,1,1,http://example.com/foo?bar=baz&qux=quux,226,0,19

and this elapsed column is the response time.
What JMeter does in the Aggregate Report listener is calculating arithmetic mean of all response times (sum of all response times divided by their count)
See Calculator class source for exact formulae used for each metric.
I guess your calculation is wrong, i.e. you're calculating average of average or something like this, hard to say without seeing your .CSV file and the Excel formula you're using.

Ah i see, i am new using jmeter so i thought i can manually added them, thankyou soo much
